# Automatically Redirect on Merged/Migrated Questions

Tags: feature-request, migration

When questions have been merged/migrated to another trilogy site, it would be nice if the page still showed that it was migrated, but include  a bar or some other indicator that said:

> Please wait: Redirecting you to Super User/Server Fault/Stack Overflow/Meta in 3..2..1..

and automatically redirect the user.

This would also benefit users who are in the middle of answering a question. Rather than get a "Page Not Found" when they submit their answer, are brought to a page that shows it was migrated and then are automatically redirected to the appropriate new home of that question

UPDATE (4 years later): Looks like a HTTP 301 would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but anyway...

I think an http 301 redirect page would be good to prevent situations like this one:

I was looking at the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283068/how-to-add-an-existing-user-into-a-group-in-linux and noticed it was on the wrong Stack Exchange site but it was closed left there instead of being moved because it receives such a good search result.

If the question was moved, would Stack Exchange leave a 301 redirect page behind as suggested by Google for this sort of thing on [Moving your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83105) and mentioned on [HTTP status codes](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/40132)

A redirect page would tell search engines to move their page score/rank data from the old page to the new one, so that the new page benefits in search results from the old page, instead of starting fresh.

Answer (score 3):

I would't want that. If the question belongs on another site (i.e. off topic) that might be enough reason for me to lose interest in it. Now I'm sent to another site I may or may not be a member of.

Besides, I might have other business on the site I *was* on. It's easy enough to click on a link to get to the migrated question.

Comment: Not if it was migrated while you were answering

Answer (score 2):

What about simply changing the migrated-stub to

> This question has been migrated to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/...
>   by: ...