# Days with a net loss of reputation ruin the reputation audit

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-audit

First thing I did on May 24th was sack 150 reputation in order to promote discussion on a question <sub>(and in turn received a lot more upvotes than actual opinions or answers! What am I paying you guys for?)</sub>, which put me at quite a disadvantage for earning reputation that day. According to my Activity page for reputation that day, I had a net result of -21 points after 10 upvotes, 2 accepted answers, one cast downvote, and the bounty payment. On May 25th, I proceeded to earn 90 reputation from 9 upvotes over the course of the entire day.

But my reputation audit thinks all of this happened in only one day! All of my efforts on the 24th have been squished into the events of the 25th! Here's the section of my reputation audit for the complete "day":

```
-- 2010-05-23 rep +10   = 2141      
 1     50989 (15)
 8     50774 (-150)
 2     50991 (10)
 2     50991 (10)
 2     50774 (10)
 1     50991 (15)
 2     50991 (10)
 2     50774 (10)
 2     50774 (10)
 3     ***** (-1)
 2     50774 (10)
 2     50774 (10)
 2     51046 (10)
 2     51046 (10)
 2     51046 (10)
 2     51104 (10)
 2     51104 (10)
 2     51122 (10)
 2     51122 (10)
 2     51133 (10)
 2     51133 (10)
 2     51131 (10)
 2     51176 (10)
-- 2010-05-25 rep +69   = 2210
```

Where that `+69` is equivalent to `-21 + 90`. It appears that the net loss incurred by the bounty makes the reputation audit skip addressing that day. It shows all of the activity correctly except for actually ending yesterday. So to summarize: **posting a bounty and not earning back all of the lost reputation appears to compress time itself and merge days**.

**UPDATE**

As [posted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51910/) by [Gnome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/54262/), this bug is not specific to bounties. Indeed, not only will **any day with any form of net loss of reputation be unmarked**, but **entire sequences of days can be collapsed at once in the reputation audit**. Until the reputation gain is resolved as positive, it will be recorded as the following day.

According to the numbers of the reputation audit (copied below for convenience), 44 downvotes occurred in the span of a single day when in reality they were cast over 6 days.

```
-- 2010-05-04 rep +10   = 2869      
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 2     34394 (10)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 2     34394 (10)
 1     45987 (15)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 1     49238 (2)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 2     45967 (10)
 2     45967 (10)
 2     44319 (10)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 2     45995 (10)
-- 2010-05-10 rep +33   = 2902      
 2     49507 (10)
 2     49507 (10)
 2     49507 (10)
 3           (-1)
 2     49507 (10)
 2     49507 (10)
 2     49507 (10)
 2     49510 (10)
 2     49510 (10)
 2     49507 (10)
 2     49507 (10)
 2     49510 (10)
 1     49510 (15)
 2     49507 (10)
 2     49510 (10)
 2     49507 (10)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 2     49507 (10)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 3           (-1)
 2     49613 (10)
 2     49613 (10)
-- 2010-05-11 rep +176  = 3078
```

Comment: I will also take a look mine tomorrow, since I set a bounty today

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it, but yes, didn't meet with your situation, since I earned all the reps back.

Comment: Oh, I could reproduce it, by deleting one post from yesterday!

Comment: This isn't specific to bounties: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51910/reputation-audit-doesnt-handle-negative-days

Comment: Good research, @TheCat . We won't get much benefit to keeping these questions separate... shall I delete mine as a dupe of yours as yours is more general?

Comment: Current convention is to keep the oldest, I've voted to close mine as a dupe, but it's still linked here to provide the information.  (You want to incorporate the update into your question?)

Comment: @TheCat I have edited the update into the question. Once again, thank you greatly for your contribution.

Comment: So it was YOU who downvoted me! Betrayor!

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce on mine too

```
-- 2010-05-24 rep +160 = 5502
8 50761 (-200)
2 50761 (10)
2 50761 (10)
2 50833 (10)
2 50761 (10)
2 50761 (10)
2 50761 (10)
2 51074 (10)
2 50761 (10)
2 51074 (10)
2 51086 (10)
2 51098 (10)
2 50969 (10)
1 51099 (2)
1 50915 (15)
2 51074 (10)
2 51098 (10)
2 50761 (10)
2 50930 (10)
2 51126 (10)
2 51086 (10)
2 51246 (10)
1 51246 (15)
2 51252 (10)
1 51255 (15)
2 51256 (10)
-- 2010-05-26 rep +57 = 5559
```

first question [50761](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-a-question-is-merged-redirect-original-question-url-to-new-one-automaticall) is the bounty I've set it yesterday
and last question [51252](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51252/how-to-search-questions-with-nottagged) is the question I posted today

Answer (score 0):

Just found this, was on my way to ask the same question.  These figures also affect the rep cap reached/exceeded figures at the bottom of the audit (see comments).  Here's mine:

```
-- 2010-03-16 rep +89   = 7287      
 2   2456631 (10)
 1   2456631 (15)
 2   2460723 (10)
 2   2460723 (10)
 2   2460723 (10)
 2   2461756 (10)
 2   2462561 (10)
 2   2462679 (10)
 2   2462679 (10)
 2   2462561 (10)
 2   2462679 (10)
 2   2462679 (10)
 2   2463105 (10)
 2   2463860 (10)
 2   2463860 (10)
 2   2463860 (10)
 2   2463860 (10)
 2   2463860 (10)
 1   2461534 (15)
 2   2463860 (10)
 2   2463860 (10)
 2   2463860 (10)
 8   2446018 (-350)
 1   2453141 (15)
 2   2446018 [0]
 2   2446018 [0]
 2   2446018 [0]
 2   2440150 (10)
 1   2463860 (15)
 3   2462679 (-2)
 1   2469122 (15)
 2   2469122 (10)
 2   2469367 (10)
 2   2469367 (10)
 2   2470148 (10)
 1   2469367 (15)
 2   2470148 (10)
 2   2470148 (10)
 1   2446542 (15)
 2   2470148 (10)
 2   2472672 (10)
 2   2472672 (10)
 2   2472672 (10)
 2   2473206 (10)
 2   2473912 (10)
 2   2473912 (10)
 2   2473912 (10)
-- 2010-03-18 rep +103  = 7390
```

Comment: What is hilarious is that midway through that, you are capped on 3 upvotes, yet it still is counted as part of another day. I wonder how that treats your "days reached"...

Comment: @Grace: that's what I was wondering. I was writing a GreaseMonkey script to show some additional stats in the user profile reputation tab so I wouldn't have noticed otherwise.  Tweaking that script I might be able to have it count the number of days I hit the cap, I'll report back here then.

Comment: @Grace: hmm.. I haven't checked my rep cap numbers yet, but I did find something weird.  My script reports that my reputation changed on 228 days (which is incorrect, as it's not accounting for this bug), yet my rep audit says *'days represented 261'*.  This seems odd as I know I haven't hit this bug on 33 days and, according to my profile I've visited SO on 319 days (I visited and did nothing on 91 days!).  So what exactly does that number (261) represent?

Comment: @Grace: the rep cap hit figure *is* incorrect.  My script calculates the same number of days it hits as the audit does, by finding `\\]`  on a "rep changed" row and then finding the next date row if hitting the cap has not already been recorded. Should I post these two issues in a separate question or do you want to add them to this one?

Comment: The rep cap exceeded figure is also incorrect.